# Postgres Update multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update multiple rows in a table.

i have table `customer` and `contact`

I need to update `customer` where the linked contact in the `contact` table has the column `city` at a certain value.
I can get the rows i need with this query

```
Select cus.id, con.city 
from customer cus, contact con 
where cus.contacts_id=con.id 
  and con.city="MyValue"
```

I know how to update one table but do not understand how to update the table when the rows are looked up from a different table.

Comment: `and con.city="MyValue"` will result in an error unless you have a column named `MyValue` somewhere. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please do not use the old JOINs (FROM comma separated tables).

Secondly, here you go:

```
UPDATE customer SET whatever = 'whatever value'
WHERE contacts_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM contact WHERE city="MyValue"
)
```